# WixSharp Borderless Custom UI

Tags: wixsharp

There is an issue I am facing. I am using Cutom Managed UI Dialogs. I want a borderless Windows form. I managed to create a borderless windows form, but when the dialog is displayed in the Installer there is a thin White bar over the top which is about 15 px thick and also I dont want Resize handles, but when the mouse pointer reaches the edges of the form resize handle shows up, but as wanted the window cannot be resized. How to solve the issue

Answer (score 0):

Your forms aren't parent windows when shown up. If you check ***form.Parent*** property you can find form owner, please try to remove all visual styles.